Bitshifting causes System.OverflowException : Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
I am trying to place a ushort into an ArraySegment<byte>, but I am unable to get the 2nd byte of the ushort due to this exception. The commented part works, but I want want to use indexing because I find it simpler.
public unsafe static void SetUshort(in ushort value, in int i1, in int i2, in ArraySegment<byte> arr)
{
     var b = (byte)((value >> 8) & 255); // Exception line
     arr[i1] = b;
     arr[i2] = (byte)value;
     //fixed (byte* p = arr.Array)
     //{
     //    var ptr = p + arr.Offset;
     //    Buffer.MemoryCopy(&value, ptr, 2, 2);
     //}
}
public static ushort GetUshort(int i1, int i2, ArraySegment<byte> arr)
{
    return (ushort)(arr[i1] << 8 | arr[i2]);
}

[Test]
[TestCase(ushort.MinValue, 0, 1)]
[TestCase((ushort)5614, 0, 1)]
[TestCase(ushort.MaxValue, 0, 1)]
public void SetUshort_Correct(ushort testValue, int index1, int index2)
{
     Helper.SetUshort(testValue, index1, index2, Body);
     Assert.That(Helper.GetUshort(index1, index2, Body), Is.EqualTo(testValue));
}

Test case with ushort.MinValue passes.

for which value are you getting an exception?

I don't know why are you using & at all.
We really just want to shift right 8 bits.
Anyway, seems like your code is compiled with checked for exceptions turned on.
We can use the unchecked statement to prevent the OverflowException
unchecked 
{
    byte b1 = (byte)(value >> 8);
    byte b2 = (byte)value;
}

The exception is thrown not because of the bitwise operations, but because of the casting.
From docs:

Bitwise and shift operations never cause overflow and produce the same
results in checked and unchecked contexts.

Try
byte b = (byte)(256);

and you will get compile time error.
If the number is not known at compile time it will still overflow with runtime error only if it's enabled explicitly - from documentation

When CheckForOverflowUnderflow is true, the default context is a
checked context and overflow checking is enabled; otherwise, the
default context is an unchecked context. The default value for this
option is false, that is, overflow checking is disabled.
You can also explicitly control the overflow-checking context for the
parts of your code by using the checked and unchecked statements.


Thank you for the answer, as to why I have the & op, I tried asking ChatGPT for help before coming here!
Its my first time writing tests so I didn't know of such error before, I assume a NUnit turns on some compiler tickbox to check for this sort of stuff?

@Shiv-iwnl np, no idea - maybe that's the defaults of NUnit. Try looking up the documentation for how to change that if it's the default.

(value >> 8) & 255 never produces values larger than 255, so your example of byte b = (byte)(256); doesn't make sense

@phuclv my example illustrates the OverFlow that will ALWAYS happen at compile time time. That's all.

but it doesn't explain the OP's case because there shouldn't be any exception in the line var b = (byte)((value >> 8) & 255) at all

@phuclv you are correct. OP's comment of where the exception occurs seems to be wrong. The exception is thrown at arr[i2] = (byte)value which gets the lower part of the ushort.
